# Apache POI issue in jenkins with open JDK11. Able to build and run the code in local but it is failing in Jenkins

Tags: excel, spring-boot, junit, apache-poi, java-11

SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
It'snot creating work book in Jenkins server with open jdk 11 there is no exception thrown. I think it's a silent exception in jenkins. But It is working in local IDE.

Updated the POI version to 4.0.1

Comment: Try with a more recent and supported version of Apache POI? [4.0.1 is over 4 years old now!](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html#4.0.1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Faced the same issue while upgrading java to java 11.

Used the below class and removed the autoSize() invocations.

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Working as expected now.